# Unfolding bag of words in pandas column (python)

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas I am trying to unfold a bag of words from the words that appear in col2. My main aim is to find all the unique words and their frequency in each different category. If a word appears twice in a category, that will count as 1 (for example "msk" and "people").

For example - 
I have a pandas column that looks like this :

```
col1        col2
Software    [msk , people , inc. ]
Software    [logical , corp , ltd ] 
Software    [imt , datalink , services. ]
Hardware    [peoples , avenue , management ] 
Hardware    [msk , techn ]
Transport   [tata , mgm , workspace , ltd ] 
Services    [msk , people , inc. ]
Services    [happy , people , party , new ]
```

My output should look something like this

```
words       category-freq .                          
msk          3
people       2
inc.         2 
logical      1
corp         1
ltd          2
```

etc. ( This is just an example I'm giving and have omitted some rows towards the end)

The bag of words in column 2 are in the form of a list.

Comment: So you want how many categories it appears in?

Comment: yes thats what i want. also the repeated words in a category will be counted as 1

Answer (score 2):

Update:

```
df.set_index('col1')['col2'].apply(pd.Series).stack().groupby(level=0).value_counts()
```

Output:

```
col1                 
Hardware   avenue        1
           management    1
           msk           1
           peoples       1
           techn         1
Services   people        2
           happy         1
           inc.          1
           msk           1
           new           1
           party         1
Software   corp          1
           datalink      1
           imt           1
           inc.          1
           logical       1
           ltd           1
           msk           1
           people        1
           services.     1
Transport  ltd           1
           mgm           1
           tata          1
           workspace     1
dtype: int64
```

Use:

```
df.col2.apply(pd.Series).stack().value_counts()
```

Output:

```
people        3
msk           3
ltd           2
inc.          2
techn         1
peoples       1
new           1
management    1
imt           1
datalink      1
mgm           1
tata          1
party         1
happy         1
services.     1
corp          1
avenue        1
logical       1
workspace     1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Not working ! This is just giving me a count in total of all the individual words. If a word is repeated in a particular category ( let's say - Hardware ) it should be counted as 1 . people should be 2 and not 3 as it comes twice in Services .

Comment: @MehulGupta Is this what you want?

Comment: HI Thankyou for the updated version. it is helpful but not quite what i'm looking for. I need to find the words which are common to all 4 categories ( which are my stopwords ). so im looking for frequencies around 3 or 4. is there a way i can do that? Thanks